# Rotate a line between x1y1 and x2y2 by angle α then finding the end of the rotated line

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

I have two points, $x$1$y$1 and $x$2$y$2 on a coordinate grid indexed in matrix convention (y increases as you go down, x increases as you go right). I want to rotate an imaginary line between $x$1$y$1 and $x$2$y$2 by angle $\alpha$ around point $x$1$y$1. Then I want to find the end of that rotated line (Where $x$2$y$2 used to be before rotation). The unit circle is also flipped in this situation, so the angle increases as you go clockwise. I've tried using rotational matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_3\\y_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha &\sin \alpha\\-\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_2 - x_1\\y_2 - y_1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{bmatrix} $$

Also, I want a positive angle to rotate anti clockwise and a negative angle to rotate clockwise

But this doesn't always work, as you can see [here](https://www.codingame.com/replay/84193290) (Look at the vehicle that says "I need to correct by ...) But sometimes it works, like at step 115, -14 should rotate the line 14 degrees clockwise, and it did. But at like step 25 it's not doing it, and I don't understand why.

Comment: On the link you provided is there a means to see your code's implementation of the math?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/ikuyudonot.cs This is the whole code, it's a bit messy sorry. Line 285 is where I do the rotation.

Comment: @IanMiller so any suggestions?

Comment: Your math is correct, so whatever’s going wrong is in your code, which is somewhat off-topic here. Have a close look at lines 300-301, though. I’d also be a bit leery of quantization errors by taking ceiling of the resulting coordinates, but that’s not going to throw you off by much unless the line is very short. (I also have to wonder why you bother to cons up a matrix and vectors when you do the calculations component by component, but that’s a different discussion.)

Comment: If I do the maths by hand from the data I'm provided it still is wrong so it's something to do with the maths I think

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with the coordinates being y increasing as you go down? I flipped the sines to take care of that... At least that's what I thought was the solution. On some angle sectors of the unit circle it seems to work and on some it doesn't, but when I flipped the sines, the sectors that didn't work suddenly works and the ones that worked stopped working